# C++ pointers accessed by other applications

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, memory

I have been playing around with C++ in my spare time.  I am completely new to manual memory management and have a lot to learn.  I am trying to do the following.

There is a database with one simple table.  I created a C++ console application program that runs on an app server and reads in the contents of that table and stores it in RAM.  It then writes the memory address to a tiny text file and goes to sleep.  A web service is running on the server (different server than the DB, except same server as the console application).  Some web site passes in a call to the web service.  Instead of hitting the database, the Web Service does one of two things.  If the web site is making its first query, it passes in a null value and the ID of the record it is looking for.  In this case, the web service reads the address from the text file and retrieves the record from RAM.  It returns the record as well as the memory address.  The web site uses the record and jams the memory address into an invisible label.  The next call, it passes the ID of the record it is looking for and the memory address.  The web service goes right to that memory address and retrieves the record.  If what it finds in that memory address can not be parsed into a record, it checks out the text file for a possible new location.

I'm hoping I'm simply doing it wrong.  Simply in theory, can this work and would it be faster than having the web service simply access a database?  Is the fact that the console application is reserving the memory preventing the web service from inspecting the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer from one process to another, in order to access shared memory, requires -- shared memory.

On a modern computer with a modern OS processes do not by default share any memory; they have separate memory spaces. The pointer you handle in C++ are **logical addresses**, which are automagically mapped on a per-process basis down to **physical addresses** used by the hardware. So a pointer value from a process A is extremely unlikely to map to the same physical address when used in a process B.

You can in principle implement shared memory or use a library that implements that, but I advice to instead use some other form of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). In Windows you have a host of possibilities including the WM_DATA window message, COM server default marshaling, mail slots (which have nothing to do with mail), general RPC, etc. For more portable code consider using network sockets.

Comment: Would inter-process communication suffer the same penalty as a call to a separate DBMS call?  Does assembly work with straight physical addresses?   Perhaps both applications could be written in C++ and use inline assembly for the necessary parts in regards to addressing.

Comment: (1) Probably not by itself, but with everything in place it might even take longer. The only way to decide is to measure. (2) It's not the language that determines whether you work with logical or physical addresses (or some intermediate form: on the ordinary PC there are three levels of addressing). Ordinary applications work with logical addresses. (3) Ordinarily the kind of optimization done by inline assembly is for things done in innermost loops, which is apparently not the scenario here. I suspect **premature optimization**, which according to Knuth is just Evil. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. Modern OS have the ability to protect different processes from messing with eachouthers address space. In fact every process has its own virtual address space which is them mapped to the physical address space by the OS. That means that address 0x00000001 of process A and address 0x00000001 of process B does not point to the same physical location in RAM.

So you can't do what you're trying to do (the easy way).

If you are doing this for the pure performance of you're web server you may want to make the web server read the data from the db and store it in its own memory instead of using another application. Or try using some commercial caching solution.

Comment: Would it help if the Web Service had originally written the text file in a previous call and put that call to sleep, thereby holding the RAM for subsequent calls or would each call be a looked upon as a separate process?

Comment: By calls I assume you mean requests that are coming to the server. I assume that you handle those requests in a different thread. If that's the case you don't need text file at all, just when the first request comes fetch the data into an array or some other data structure. Store that in a "global" place (probably global variable/private field etc). When the next request comes use that "global" holder to get the data from it. Beware of multiple thread accessing the array/holder at the same time. You need to implement thread synchronization.

Comment: Take a look at that article http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreaded2B.php